# Nonclustered index uses key into clustered index instead of address?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for SQL server 2008 R2 is stated:

> Wide keys are a composite of several columns or several large-size columns. The key values from the clustered index are used by all nonclustered indexes as lookup keys. Any nonclustered indexes defined on the same table will be significantly larger because **the nonclustered index entries contain the clustering key** and also the key columns defined for that nonclustered index.

Does this mean, that when there is a search using non-clustered index, than the clustered indes is search also? I originally thought that the non-clustered index contains ditrectly the address of the page (block) with the row it references. From the text above it seems that it contains just the key from the non-clustered index instead of the address.

Could somebody explain please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what happens:

- SQL Server searches for your search value in the non-clustered index
- if a match is found, in that index entry, there's also the **clustering key** (the column or columns that make up the clustered index)
- with that clustered key, a **key lookup** (often also called **bookmark lookup**) is now performed - the clustered index is searched for that value given
- when the item is found, the entire data record at the leaf level of the clustered index navigation structure is present and can be returned

SQL Server does this, because using a physical address would be really really bad:

- if a page split occurs, all the entries that are moved to a new page would be updated
- for all those entries, **all nonclustered** indices would also have to be updated

and this is really really bad for performance.

This is one of the reasons why it is beneficial to use limited column lists in `SELECT` (instead of always `SELECT *`) and possibly even include a few extra columns in the nonclustered index (to make it a **covering** index). That way, you can avoid unnecessary and expensive bookmark lookups.

And because the clustering key is included in each and every nonclustered index, it's highly important that this be a **small** and narrow key - optimally an `INT IDENTITY` or something like that - and not a huge structure; the clustering key is the most replicated data structure in SQL Server and should be a small as possible.

The fact that these bookmark lookups are relatively expensive is also one of the reasons why the query optimizer might opt for an index scan as soon as you select a larger number of rows - at at time, just scanning the clustered index might be cheaper than doing a lot of key lookups.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. COuld you laso provide info why is that so? Isn't it faster to have the address directly? I know that the search in the clustered index is fast and retrieval of data also, but why don't save the time of the search in the clustered index and not access the data directly? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @OndraPeterka: having a physical address would just have a lot more drawbacks and much more effort would be required in case of a page split.